# Получить текстовые поля из PDF

Tags: pdf, текст, python-3.6

PDF файлы имеют структуру, где есть названия полей и через двоеточие значения. 
Следующим кодом получаю текстовое содержимое pdf файла:

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObject = open('Build.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
count = pdfReader.numPages
for i in range(count):
    page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    print(page.extractText())
```

В тексте значения полей соединяются (без пробелов и др. разделителей) с названиями следующих полей, не зная которые, отделить одно от другого трудно...
Как это исправить, может можно обратиться к строкам или ячейкам таблицы PDF?